# Destructor, doesn't delete my object

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, destructor

I have big problem- namely my destructor doesn't delete object, in my code which i will paste underneath in main when i call `l3.~list();` it removes only singly linked list(which is good), but it doesn't remove char* name, even though I am stating in my destructor `delete [] name;`. Any ideas whats wrong?

Here is the code;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class list{

    struct lista
    {
        int num;
        char* word;
        lista* next;
    };
    lista* head;
    char* name;
    public:
    list(char* name1){head=NULL;name=new char[strlen(name1)+1];strcpy(name,name1);}
    char getChar(int key, int index);
    void setChar(int key, int index, char c);
    void insert(int number,char* txt);
    void remove(int number);
    void print();
    list(const list &o);
    list& operator=(const list &x);
    ~list();
};
void list::insert(int number,char* txt){
    lista* ptr,*tmp;
    ptr=head;
    lista* newlista=new lista;
    newlista->num=number;
    newlista->next=NULL;
    newlista->word= new char[strlen(txt)+1];
    strcpy(newlista->word,txt);
    if(head==NULL){
        head=newlista;
        newlista->next=NULL;
    }
    else while(ptr!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(txt,ptr->word)>=0){
            if(ptr->next!=NULL && strcmp(txt,ptr->next->word)<=0)
            {
                tmp=ptr->next;
                ptr->next=newlista;
                newlista->next=tmp;
                break;
            }
            else if(ptr->next!=NULL && strcmp(txt,ptr->next->word)>0)
                ptr=ptr->next;
            else
            {
                //next is empty
                ptr->next=newlista;
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            //txt mniejszy niz w 1szym elemencie
            newlista->next=head;
            head=newlista;
            break;
        }      
    }
    return;
}

void list::print(){
    cout<<name<<";"<<endl;
    lista *druk;
    druk=head;
    while(druk!=NULL){
        cout<<"txt: "<<druk->word<<" | "<<"num: "<<druk->num<<endl;
        druk=druk->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return;
}


void list::remove(int number){
    if(head==NULL)
        return;
    if(head->num==number){
        lista* ptr=head;
        head=head->next;
        delete [] ptr->word;
        delete ptr;
        return;
    }
    lista* ptr=head;
    while(ptr->next!=NULL && ptr->next->num!=number)
        ptr=ptr->next;
    if(ptr->next==NULL){
        cout<<number<<" element not found"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    lista* todelete=ptr->next;
    ptr->next=todelete->next;
    delete [] todelete->word;
    delete todelete;
    return;
}
list::list(const list &o)
{
    lista *xtr = o.head;
    head=NULL;// bez tego nie działa
    lista *etr=head;// nastawic etr na head?
    while (xtr)
    {
        lista* ntr = new lista;
        if (!ntr)
        {
            cerr << "list::CopyConstructor: Allocation memory failure!";
            cerr << endl;
            break;
        }
        ntr->num = xtr->num;
        ntr->word= new char[strlen(xtr->word)+1];
        strcpy(ntr->word,xtr->word);
        ntr->next = NULL;
        if (head)
            etr->next = ntr;    
        else
            head = ntr;
        etr = ntr; // keep track of the last element in *this
        xtr = xtr->next;
    }
    name = new char[strlen(o.name)+5];
    strcpy(name,o.name);
    strcat(name,"Copy");
}

list& list::operator=(const list &x)
{
    if(this==&x)
        return *this;
    lista *etr=head;
    while(etr) // removing list from this
    {
        etr=etr->next;
        delete head;
        head=etr;
    }
    lista *xtr=x.head;
    while(xtr)
    {
        int copied=xtr->num;
        lista *ntr= new lista;
        ntr->word=new char[strlen(xtr->word)+1];
        if (!ntr) 
        {
            cerr << "list::operator=: Allocation memory failure!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        ntr->num=copied;
        strcpy(ntr->word,xtr->word);
        ntr->next=NULL;
        if (!head)
            head = ntr;
        else
            etr->next = ntr;

        etr = ntr; // keep track of the last element in *this
        xtr = xtr->next;
    }
    char *name=new char[strlen(x.name)+1];
    strcpy(name,x.name);
    return *this;
}

list::~list()
{
    cout<<"Object with name:"<<name<<" destroyed!"<<endl;
    delete [] name;
    lista *dtr=head;
    while(dtr) // removing lista from this
    {
        dtr=dtr->next;
        delete [] head->word;
        delete head;
        head=dtr;
    }

}
void f();
void f(){
    list o("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    o.insert(4,"kazio");
    o.insert(100,"312jh31io2");
    o.insert(34,"kz31231azio");
    o.insert(1020,"123213312jh31io2");
    o.insert(213123,"z3213io");
    o.insert(1100,"zdrf312jh31io2");
    o.print();
}
int main(){
    list l1("lista1");
    l1.insert(5,"Endian");
    l1.insert(7,"Endianness");
    l1.insert(100,"Hexediting");
    l1.insert(34,".mil");

    l1.print();
    list l2(l1); // usage of CC - the same as list l2=l1; 
    l2.print();
    l2.remove(5);
    l2.print();
    l1.print();

    list l3("asajnment");
    l3=l2=l1;
    l3.print();
    l2.print();
    f();
    l3.print();
    l3.~list(); // here i use destructor on l3
    l3.print(); // l3 is being printed with weird name, even though it should be destroyed
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling the destructor directly?  You're not supposed to do that.

Comment: to check if it works properly?

Comment: Well, it can't, because doing this isn't proper in the first place.

Comment: Please read a decent C++ book - this is a complicated language and you can easily pick up some nasty misconceptions.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, so are you telling me that my destructor is fine? Because something puzzles me, namely when i cancel out the line where i call out destructor and when i set breakpoint after return 0 in main, char* name of objects get weird names, i will show u screenshot [IMG]http://i40.tinypic.com/2yzfuco.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: If you set a breakpoint after destructor invocation you can see proper values or garbage - it is the undefined behaviour. You should not refer to deleted objects.

Comment: Also, checking if the pointer returned by `new` is not null is unnecessary, because when allocation fails, an exception of type `std::bad_alloc` is thrown. There is a nothrow version of new, but you probably doesn't want to use it. From filenames, etc I see that this is homework. Just for my curiosity - for what college?

Comment: Reduce your example to about 20 lines of code.

Answer (score 5):

Calling any method after invoking destructor results in undefined behaviour - it may or may nor work and it can produce strange results.

Also, you are not supposed to call the destructor directly:

- When the object is allocated on stack, it is destroyed automatically when the scope ends. (Scope is the thing between braces `{}`)
- When the object is allocated on heap, using `new`, it should be destroyed using `delete`.

Comment: Even doing nothing results in undefined behaviour! When the object goes out of scope, the destructor is called automatically, so in this case, it gets called twice. Bad news.

Comment: Also, you mustn't call the destructor directly on objects with static storage duration (i.e. declared outside functions and classes, or declared `static`); these are destroyed automatically when the program exits. The only time you'd call it directly is if the object were created with placement `new`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ destructors are not like deallocation functions as you might write in C. They're better: in the [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII), you have destruction of your objects scheduled to the very moment they exit scope. That means you usually don't have to care for freeing resources at all: just wait until the object is no longer needed (because it can't be accessed), at that points it gets automatically removed (which includes calling the destructor, yes, and that's the only way in which it may be called safely). So well-written C++ is in many ways as good as garbage-collected languages, but without some of their drawbacks.

The easiest way to get the benefits of RAII is to use standard containers and smart pointers. In your case, replace `lista* next` with `std::unique_ptr<lista> next` and `char* word` with `std::string word`, and all is fine without the need to define a destructor *at all*.

Answer (score 1):

There is so much wrong with this code that I don't know where to start...

- use std::string
- use a std::map to associate int values with the strings. This will pretty much already do what you want.
- don't call the destructor for anything that was not new'd. To delete something use delete/delete[] and don't call the destructor directly. If you do use new, use the RAII idiom using managing objects such as std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr to avoid having to manually call delete/delete[] and to write exception safe code

Here is a somewhat improved version. Notice that there is not a single call to new/delete.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>

class list
{
public:
    explicit
    list( std::string n ) : name( n ) {}

    ~list() { std::cout << "~list:" << name << std::endl; }

    void list::insert(int number, std::string const& txt ){
        items.insert( std::make_pair(number,txt));
    }

    void list::remove(int number){
        items.erase( number );
    }

    void print( ){
        std::cout << name << ";" << std::endl;
        for( Items::const_iterator it = items.begin(), end = items.end(); it != end; ++it  )
        {
            std::cout << "num: " << it->first << " | " << "txt: " << it->second << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    typedef std::map<int,std::string> Items;
    Items items;
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    list l1( "lista1" );
    l1.insert( 5, "Endian");
    l1.insert( 7, "Endianness");
    l1.insert( 100, "Hexediting");
    l1.insert( 34, ".mil");
    // extra scope so the destructor of l2 is called before call to getchar
    { 
        list l2( l1 ); 
        l2.remove( 5 );
        l2.print();
    }
    l1.print();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of making sure that your members are not being accessed by mistake after destruction is to set all pointers to NULL after deleting them.

That way, you're assured that nobody can get to your sensitive data afterwards, because you're no longer pointing to it. And you can call the destructor again without bad side effects, because calling delete on a NULL pointer is allowed and does nothing.

Comment: I believe this is very relevant to his issue, but you should explain how and why

Comment: The other answers already explained most; it's best to make sure that objects don't get accessed after destruction. So I didn't need to explain that again, I was just pointing out that IF you have a situation where the program might access objects after destroying them, you can take safety measures.

Answer (score -1):

If you print the memory state of your object after deleting it, you will see the value stay until you don't alloc a new object. The memory allocated for your program can only go bigger. When you delete data, they are not set to '0', just marked as free for the next alloc object.

EDIT: I mean if you create a new object with uninitialized values just after free, he can get back the old value stored in memory.

Comment: I don't think that's right.  The memory allocated for a program can go down.  You seem to be confused about how virtual memory works as well.

Comment: I experienced that, I also read that on official documentation :
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/free/
Maybe I don't understand well :/
Effectivlely you can get segfault.

Comment: After memory is freed, it is UB to access it, but in practice: sometimes it is released to the OS, but usually what happens is what you described.